# Is it possible to express 2 week periods as a CRON expression as implemented by Quartz?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

Starting from the Jan 1st 2014 the 2 week periods yield the following schedule:

1. Jan 14
2. Jan 28
3. Feb 11
4. Feb 25
5. Mar 11
6. Mar 25
7. Apr 8
8. Apr 22
9. May 6
10. May 20

etc ...

This is not an idle question. Some companies have exactly 2 week long pay periods, meaning they have 26 pay periods per year rather than 24 for a company that pays twice a month as opposed to every two weeks exactly. I want to know whether I can express the pay schedule of such a company using a CRON expression.

Finally, it is possible that no CRON expression can be used to express what I want, but the Quartz scheduler may have some tricky solution that can ultimately produce the needed schedule. Note, that I can always create a calendar scheduler with 26 explicit triggers - one per pay period. I am not talking about this kind of solution.

I am using the .NET port of the Quartz library.

**EDIT**

An equally good schedule would be **exactly every other Sunday**. Note, it is not equivalent to **every 2nd and 4th Sunday**. Indeed, if a month has 5 Sundays, then the first schedule may result in three instances for that particular month, if started from the first Sunday. Whereas the second schedule always yields exactly two instances per month.

I have a feeling such schedules cannot be expressed in CRON, because they carry over from month to month, whereas CRON resets its month trigger each time a new month starts.

**EDIT2**

I guess what I am looking for could be expressed by an imaginary **DayOfYear** CRON field. Helas, no such thing exists. But then again, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using version 2.0 then you can use the [CalendarIntervalTrigger](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/531695b8-4dcb-3038-2b95-c749c799d94b.htm), set the [RepeatIntervalUnit](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/1cbfa0a8-e2cb-761c-4e9b-bcb50411591d.htm) to weeks and the RepeatInteval to 2 so that it fires every 2 weeks.

Comment: Yes, it is better than 26 explicit triggers.