# Scheduling a job to run every Nth week and specific week days starting on specific date with Quartz (Scala)

Tags: scala, cron, quartz-scheduler

In continuation of: 
[What is the most reliable way to schedule a job with cron scheduler is Quartz that repeats every N days starting from a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315919/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-schedule-a-job-with-cron-scheduler-is-quartz-th)
&
[Absolutely unexplainable results for cron based scheduler in Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300176/absolutely-unexplainable-results-for-cron-based-scheduler-in-quartz/38301203?noredirect=1#comment64057776_38301203)

There is another question regarding possibilities of scheduling with quartz. And the difference between the two above and this one and the fact that I am trying to execute more than a single job for the target period (e.g. Mon, Fri every 4th week)

Let's assume that a user needs to execute a task every 4th week on Wednesday & Friday starting from a specific date.

Of course, I can setup a cron scheduler that will look something like this:

> 0 0 12 ? 1/4 WED,FRI *

But we are beck to the same problem as described in the linked posts. What this cron expression really mean, is execute the job on Wednesday & Friday of every 4th week of the month.

Another option is to use, calendar interval schedule builder (the perfectly resolves the problem for as long as there is only one day of the week that needs to be considered); however, it does not allow to specify days of a week, but simply calculates the true 4 weeks worth of time based on the start date.

How, if possible, to schedule a job with Quartz, that will be executed every 4th (or any Nth week) on more than a single day of the week? Is it possible to achieve it without multiple triggers?

Thanks,

Comment: Write a job that runs on your start date. That job creates (or just enables) a job with a schedule of `0 0 12 ? 1/4 WED,FRI *`

Comment: Well, that problem is actually resolved by quartz itself, the problem is (as described in the original question) it will execute the job every 4th week of a month and not every 4 weeks regardless of a month.

Comment: Ah, gotcha (was doing drive-by comments while in a boring conference call)

Comment: I think the answer to this question might be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633029/is-it-possible-to-express-2-week-periods-as-a-cron-expression-as-implemented-by?rq=1

Comment: Right, this one will help, but in this case I am forced to create more than one trigger to accommodate cases with two more than a single run per week. I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same thing with a single trigger

Comment: You asked the same thing yesterday ... After linking to a page with the answer, that you apparently didn't bother to read fully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315919/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-schedule-a-job-with-cron-scheduler-is-quartz-th

Comment: Dima, I am very happy that you really smart, and you did help me on the other question. Thank you for that. But, I would suggest you to read both of these posts again, and you'll see that these are related, but completely different problem. Unless, I am missing something...

Comment: @Dima How about the case when I need to execute a job, for example, on Nth Friday of every 2nd/3rd month? Is it still the same problem?

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky indeed, I am smart. But being smart is not really needed to answer questions like this. You just need to spend some time reading documentation. What is I showed you how to make a schedule for every third Friday, and tomorrow you wanted to know how to do it for every summer solstice? Would that be a new "related but completely different" question?

Answer (score 0):

So, after long digging around, it seems like the only way to solve it with existing Quartz tools is to manage this type of scheduling with more that one trigger (one for every weekday).
Hopefully that helps somebody.